# Using GDAL in Python 3.7

Tags: gdal

Recently installed the GDAL software on my Windows 10 computer for the first time. Process indicated the install was successful.
When I did the command `gdalinfo --version` I get gdal 3.0.0 with the release date

I am not sure what the syntax of the pip install command should be 
I see a suggestion of "pygdal>=2.1.2<2.1.3" for older versions.
Tried pip install "pygal>=3.0.0" and get a message 
"Could not find a version that satisfices the requirement 3.0.0. 
Second message states no matching distribution found. Last number of versions shown is 2.4.0

Comment: From the website http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php. I selected version Release-1911-x64-gdal-3.0.0 mspserver-7-4-0. The website https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows has instructions for downloading. Other sites showed me the pip install command

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/338821/edit) your question with additional info so it's in the question, not scattered through comments. Your 2nd link also shows you how to install the GDAL python bindings. Don't use `pip` for GDAL unless you have a C++ compiler installed.